# The desired archetype does not exist-- org.apache.maven.archetype.quickstart:1.0

Tags: maven

I'm creating a new project using Maven but I get an error whenever I write this command -

"mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=TestCases -DartifactId=RealTimeFramework -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven.archetype.quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false"

The error message is:the desired archetype does not exist-- org.apache.maven.archetype.quickstart:1.0

[Screenshot
 of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruPef.png)

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to use a Maven archetype which does not exist:

https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=maven.archetype.quickstart

You're either trying to use [this one](http://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/), case in which you got the name (`-DarchetypeArtifactId`) wrong (you're using `maven.archetype.quickstart` instead of `maven-archetype-quickstart`), or if you want another archetype, you need to edit your question and clarify which.